# Оптимизация UI элементов

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть `View Model` в которой содержится состояние объекта :

```
public enum EntityState
{
Created,
Edited,
Undefined
}
```

В окне у меня рисуется порядка 100-400 визуальных представлений этих VM. Прошлый программист нарисовал 4 иконки, они из себя представляют простые геометрические фигуры, залитые разным цветом. Иконки в формате Png.

Вопрос, если я возьму конвертер перепишу его, и вместо картинки буду отдавать Canvas/Path/Polygon/Border, это повлияет на производительность? И вообще имеет ли смысл такая оптимизация? ( И оптимизация ли это ? )

Comment: Производительность, не подкреплённая цифрами (профилирование, счётчики производительности) -- это страшный грех. Возьмите профайлер и когда удивитесь, что bottle neck находится в совершенно другом месте -- вспомните историю про то, что ищут потерю не там, где потеряли, а там где светло.

Comment: Как оказалось при 40т элементов расход на canvase 81мб. На Image 74